# Where to edit text preview length in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm very new to Wordpress so I apologise if this is a stupid question.

I am using [this](http://evergreenpa.org/themes/evergreen-sports/category/blog/) template and I have set up the same page for latest post as , however on my page news show full content while I want it to be like on the example, with text preview and Continue Reading button.

I've checked everywhere but I couldn't find which page I need to edit for these category news. I know I have to insert `the_excerpt();` instead of the `the_content();` but I don't know where. I was able to find this for the home page, but not for this sub-page.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about WordPress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_excerpt();` or `the_content();` need to be within a post loop or a single post or something. It depends what you are displaying, I imagine you will have some loop of posts and within that you could call either. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt for more info on the differences.

If you want to change the length of the excerpt you need to add the following code to you functions.php file.

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

This will change excerpt length without modifying core wordpress files.

Comment: Thanks for this but what I was asking about which file to edit to change the_content(); to the_excerpt(); ? This is my problem, I can't find which file controls setting for this category blog.

Comment: Depending on the template wordpress could use 1 of 5 files for the category page. Will try them in these order... 1 - category-slug.php, 2 - category-ID.php. 3 - category.php, 4 - archive.php 5 - index.php    I found this on the WP site at https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates one of those files will certainly have the bit you trying to edit.

Comment: It was the archive.php thanks!